# How does one arrive at the asymptotic expressions for the bessel functions?

Tags: asymptotics, special-functions, approximation

It is known that Bessel functions for large arguments will behave as exp or cos/sin however I was wondering how does one arrive at those results. The motivation being that I would like to use these better approximations to evaluate them for large values analytically.

From wikipedia

[image]
[image]

From here http://upload.wikimedia.org/math/0/3/2/0327db30fc62796e50cced64f823128d.png

[image]

Comment: Just curious, why are you interested in using the approximations to evaluate them analytically? Back in the 1960's, this would be a valid question, but today virtually all computer algebra systems and math packages have arbitrary-precision evaluators for all special functions, including Bessel functions, so this doesn't really make a lot of sense.

Comment: So what is happening for example is I have a J(r) / J(r_Ref) and sometimes r == r_Ref and then the thing gives a nan as both evaluate to inf. In that case an approximation would be useful for an analytic solution. Now if you have a link for the arbitrary precision tool please let me know. (i'm using python) (I'll also look it up further)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answers part of the question. After looking into the textbook @Antonio Vargas suggested I found the equations I was after:

From: G. N. Watson, "A Treatise on the Theory of Bessel Functions", 2nd Edition, 1948.

$$
J_v (z) = \left(\frac{2}{πz} \right)^{1/2} \left[ \cos \left(z - \frac{\nu \pi}{2} - \frac{\pi}{4} \right) \sum_{m=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^m (\nu, 2m)}{(2z)^{2m}} \\
-\sin \left(z - \frac{\nu \pi}{2} - \frac{\pi}{4} \right) \sum_{m=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^m (\nu, 2m+1)}{(2z)^{2m+1}} \right]
$$
$$
Y_v (z) = \left(\frac{2}{πz} \right)^{1/2} \left[ \sin \left(z - \frac{\nu \pi}{2} - \frac{\pi}{4} \right) \sum_{m=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^m (\nu, 2m)}{(2z)^{2m}} \\
+\cos \left(z - \frac{\nu \pi}{2} - \frac{\pi}{4} \right) \sum_{m=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^m (\nu, 2m+1)}{(2z)^{2m+1}} \right]
$$
$$
K_v(z) = \left(\frac{\pi}{2z}\right)^{1/2} e^{-z} \sum_{m=0}^\infty \frac{(\nu,m)}{(2z)^m}
$$
$$
I_v(z) = \frac{1}{(2\pi z)^{1/2}} e^{z} \sum_{m=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^m(\nu,m)}{(2z)^m} + \frac{1}{(2\pi z)^{1/2}} e^{-z+(\nu+1/2)\pi i} \sum_{m=0}^\infty \frac{(\nu,m)}{(2z)^m}
$$

Also:

$$
(\nu, m) = \prod_{i=1}^m \frac{4 \nu ^2 - (2i-1)^2}{4 i}
$$

Answer (score 2):

Primarily the asymptotic expansions are obtained by analyzing integral representations of the functions.

For reference, the leading-order term in the asymptotic expansion for $J_\nu(x)$ as $x \to \infty$ is derived in appendix A.1. of Stein and Shakarchi's *Complex Analysis*.  The complete asymptotic expansions of the various Bessel functions are derived and discussed in great detail in chapter 7 of Watson's *A Treatise on the Theory of Bessel Functions*.

Comment: posted a follow up http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/769072/why-does-the-asymptotic-equation-of-the-modified-bessel-of-the-second-kind-iv