# Why does the asymptotic equation of the modified Bessel of the second kind (Iv) have an imaginary part?

Tags: asymptotics, special-functions, approximation

This is a follow up to this question.

[How does one arrive at the asymptotic expressions for the bessel functions?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/765203/how-does-one-arrive-at-the-asymptotic-expressions-for-the-bessel-functions/768029#768029)

After looking at: G. N. Watson, "A Treatise on the Theory of Bessel Functions", 2nd Edition, 1948.

I arrived at the solution, however, I noticed that the results for finite real z will be complex for Iv. I understand that in the limit the complex part will be zero but I'm just confused as to it's existence in the first place. For integer $\nu$ it is either +i or -i.

$$
I_v(z) = \frac{1}{(2\pi z)^{1/2}} e^{z} \sum_{m=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^m(\nu,m)}{(2z)^m} + \frac{1}{(2\pi z)^{1/2}} e^{-z+(\nu+1/2)\pi i} \sum_{m=0}^\infty \frac{(\nu,m)}{(2z)^m}
$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As an asymptotic series for $z \to +\infty$ the terms with the imaginary component will not contribute since they are exponentially small compared to the terms in the first series.  However, as $z \to -\infty$ the terms of the first series are exponentially small compared to those of the second series, so only the terms in the second series contribute.

For $\nu = 1/2$, for instance, $I_\nu(z)$ is complex for $z < 0$, and the second series captures the asymptotic behavior as $z \to -\infty$.

Comment: excellent point, I can't believe I missed it, so I guess it's fine to ignore the second term as long as I restrict z to be positive.

Comment: Right, or at least as long as you restrict it to some sector strictly inside the right half-plane.